# Highlight the date format in pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, date

I want to highlight all the dates in the pandas data frame in one column.

index   A

0         24

1          32-35

2     10/01/2016

3      02/20/2017

4      02/20/2017

5      02/20/2017

Comment: Welcome, what did you try? Try this solution https://towardsdatascience.com/highlighting-columns-in-pandas-dataframe-bf2ff77d00bc

Answer (score 1):

Idea is test if `datetime`s with convert values by [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) with test if not missing value, because `errors='coerce'` return `NaN` for no datetimes:

```
def color_datetimes(val):

    color = 'red' if pd.notna(pd.to_datetime(val, errors='coerce')) else 'black'
    return 'color: %s' % color


df.style.applymap(color_datetimes, subset=['A']).to_excel('file.xlsx', index=False)
```

Comment: This code also highlight non date format data also. I.e idealy it should only highlight last 4 records but it's highlighting all the data

Comment: @ParvJain - Can you post `print (df['A'].tolist())` ? Fo rme working well, so problem in data

Comment: Consider this as a data [datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 9, 0, 0), 13, datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 12, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 10, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 10, 0, 0)]

Comment: for me it's highlighting all the frame data. However data as per above comment even 13 is also getting printed

Comment: then just modify your condition test, `if isinstance(x, datetime): do this: else: do that`